# How to add country code to product url?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, url-routing

I want to add `%country%` to the product URL. Under `%country%`, I mean `$woocommerce->customer->get_country()`. At least as a parameter, like `domain.com/shop/productname?country=germany`. But in the end, I want to achieve something like `domain.com/germany/shop/productname`.

I tried to do something with the following functions:

```
add_rewrite_endpoint()
add_rewrite_rule()
add_rewrite_tag()
```

But all the code examples that I have met put me stumped. 
I'm not very good in routing. If someone describes my case - I will be very grateful!

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/custom-field-values-in-permalink/3517#3517 This may help you

Comment: @MujeebuRahman thank you! It really allows you to change the URL structure (like domain.com/gb/shop/productname), but I keep getting a 404 error when click that link.
Terms of permanent links have been updated.